# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel- Only on a server. Works on development box

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, networking, tls1.2

I have a simple console application that connects to a web service which uses certificate authentication. I am using Tls1.2 protocol. It works as expected when executed from my development box but receive an exception when executed from the server.

I have already verified that the client certificate is properly installed in the server and can be accessible by the application. Additionally, I have also verified that TLS 1.2 is enabled in the server and the server IP address has been white-listed on the web-services. Literally all the settings are same except the box.

I am baffled that it works on my development box but not on the server.  The error message I get on the server is

**An error occurred while sending the request. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**

Any insight is highly appreciated.

```
X509Certificate cert = Utilities.GetClientCertificate();
ClinicalTrialMapping ctContent = null;
Console.WriteLine(cert);
        if (cert != null)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            Console.WriteLine(ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);
            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();

            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;


            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"];
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                try
                {
                    string url = "test.php";
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await 
                    client.GetAsync(url);
                 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
```

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to capture TLS handshakes and analyze the packets to learn what's up.

Comment: What is the os on the development machine and on the server?
We have a similar problem which occurs sometimes on windows 7 but never on windows 10